# Entity Framework and adding POCOs without adding child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So perhaps I'm addressing this problem the wrong way, but I wanted to get the opinion from you fine people on StackOverflow about how to more correctly do this.

I've got a program that has to retrieve information from a repository around an Entity Framework 6.0 code-first context, do some work on the information contained and then it adds a new record to the database.

Anyway, here's the simplified look at the class I'm retrieving from EF through the repository:

```
public class Product
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public virtual ProductCategory Category { get;set; }
  public string Name { get;set; }
}
```

I then build a ProcessedProduct with the following definition and pass in the previously retrieved Product as the BaseProduct:

```
public class ProcessedProduct
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public virtual Product BaseProduct { get;set; }
}
```

I use a repository layer that I saw on an EF lesson on Pluralsight and have purposed here. I've added all the relevant bits below:

```
public class MyContext : BaseContext<MyContext>, IMyContext
{
  //Lots of IDbSets for each context
  public void SetModified(object entity)
  {
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
  }

  public void SetAdd(object entity) 
  {
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
  }
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
  private readonly IMyContext _context;

  public MyRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
  {
    _context = uow.Context as IMyContext;
  }

  public ProcessedProduct FindProcessedProduct(int id)
  {
    return _context.ProcessedProducts.Find(id);
  }

  public ProductCategory FindCategory(int id) 
  {
    return _context.Categories.Find(id);
  }

  public int AddProcessedProductWithoutProduct(ProcessedProduct newRecord)
  {
    newRecord.Product = null;
    Save();
    return newRecord.Id;
  }

  public int UpdateProcessedProductWithProductButWithoutChildProperties(int processedProductId, int productId)
  {
    var processedProduct = FindProcessedProduct(processedProductId);
    processedProduct.BaseProduct = FindProduct(productId);
    processedProduct.BaseProduct.Category = null;
    _context.SetModified(product);
    Save();

    return processedProduct.Id;
  }

  public int UpdateProductChildren(int processedProductId, int categoryId) 
  {
    var processedProduct = FindProcessedProduct(processedProductId);
    var category = FindCategory(categoryId);
    processedProduct.BaseProduct.Category = category;
    _context.SetModified(product);
    Save();

    return processedProduct.Id;
  }
}
```

And finally, here's the portion that pulls it all together:

```
try
{
  //Create the processed product without the product instance
  var processedProductId = repo.AddProcessedProductWithoutProduct(finishedProduct);

  //Now, update this processed product record with the product. This way, we don't create a  
  //duplicate product.
  processedProductId = repo.UpdateProcessedProductWithProductButWithoutChildProperties(processedProductId, product.Id);

  //Finally, update the category
  processedProductId = repo.UpdateProductChildren(processedProductId, product.Category.Id);

  //Done!
}
```

When I attempt to insert this ProcessedProduct into EF, it correctly creates the ProcessedProduct record, but it also creates a new Product and new Category row. I've tried manually changing the change tracking for each object so ProcessedProduct would be 'added' and the others would be either 'modified' or 'unchanged', but I would get foreign key reference exceptions thrown by Entity Framework.

My "fix" was to simply break this up into a number of different calls:

1. I create the new ProcessedProduct record, but I assign the Product value to null.
2. I query for that ProcessedProduct record with the Id, query for the appropriate Product with its Id and assign that Product to the newly retrieved ProcessedProduct record. However, I have to null out the Category property or else this will add a new duplicate Category record. I save and the ProcessedProduct record is modified.
3. Finally, I query the ProcessedProduct once more as well as the ProductCategory and then assign that ProductCategory to the Category property of the ProcessedProduct.BaseProduct. I can save once more and now I've created all the records I need without making any of the duplicates.

However, this approach seems quite convoluted since all I originally wanted to do is save the new parent record and simply not create duplicate child records. Is there a better way to go about doing this that I'm missing? Thanks!

Edit: And I guess the larger question is say I have a complex object with a whole bunch of these child complex objects. What's the easiest way to create a new parent without having to go through the entire graph of child objects to update the parent with them one layer at a time?

Comment: did you miss the BaseProductId (or something else) in you ProcessedProduct? or you have it but didn't show it?

Comment: No, if I look at the debug, all the Ids are there as expected (it's where I actually get the ProductId for the future lookups). If I look at the originally created ProcessedProduct, I can get the Id for the ProcessedProduct.Product.Id as well as ProcessedProduct.Product.Category.Id.

Comment: Just usually I create explicitly add id of dependent entities. In that case you can try just to create new ProcessedProduct setting that Id.

Comment: Can you show us the code how you insert the ProcessedProduct?

Comment: @J.W. Code added above. Let me know if you need any more than that, though I think that about covers it.

Comment: @Nicolai, the problem with that is if I have a huge chain of child entities, that's an awful lot of code I'll have to dig through to manually just specify the Id for every single one of them. Surely this has been addressed in the framework somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend not setting Product & Category as navigation properties when editing. As you saw when you add the graph of processed product (with a product & category attached) to the EF context, it's marking everything in the graph as added and does inserts on everything.
The pattern I always recommend (and Nikolai also suggested in his comment, so up-vote his comment like I did :)) is to include the FK IDs in your entity and set those values, not the navigations. e.g. 
newRecord.ProductId=theProductIdValue.

I've had many people cry "but foreign keys? ewwww! They will make my classes so dirty and impure!" but after they see how much easier it is to code things without tangling with the navigations in these scenarios, they have come back to say "okay, it was worth it!"

BTW if you are talking about my EF in the Enterprise course, I have a whole module about dealing with this problem...it's called something bout graphs in disconnected scenarios. :)